# How to fix Cyrillic letters not decoding

Tags: python-3.x, decoding

I send a request to a site, parse the data and then try to output it, but it outputs some strange encoding and I don't know how to fix it.

```
body_clean = re.search('"body_clean": "', r.text)
body_clean1 = re.search('", "attachments', r.text)
body = r.text[body_clean.end():body_clean1.start()]
print (body)
```

I need the output:

```
Сдать после каникул, 15 апреля.&;Убедительная просьба оформлять решение &;как положено&; в соответствии с тем &;как учили&;, а не так, будто бы вы его на коленке за 5 минут перед сдачей делали. Писать разборчиво и аккуратно.
```

But I get the output

```
\u0421\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c \u043f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0443\u043b, 15 \u0430\u043f\u0440\u0435\u043b\u044f.&nbsp;\r\n\u0423\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044c\u0431\u0430 \u043e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043b\u044f\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0435\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u043e&quot; \u0432 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0438 \u0441 \u0442\u0435\u043c &quot;\u043a\u0430\u043a \u0443\u0447\u0438\u043b\u0438&quot;, \u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043a, \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0442\u043e \u0431\u044b \u0432\u044b \u0435\u0433\u043e \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0435 \u0437\u0430 5 \u043c\u0438\u043d\u0443\u0442 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434 \u0441\u0434\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0439 \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043b\u0438. \u041f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0447\u0438\u0432\u043e \u0438 \u0430\u043a\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e.
```

Upd:

Tried this code, get the same output

```
encoded = body.encode("utf-8")
        decoded = str(encoded,'utf-8')
        print(decoded)
```

Page info from which I parsed the data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 11:47:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: How do you make request? How do you accept request? What is your `Content-Type` header?

Comment: Make a request through r = requests.get and don't use a content type header

Comment: Should I use one? If I should, which one?

Answer (score 0):

The output you're getting is a string of unicode characters. Encode the body in `utf-8` to get a bytes string, then decode it:

```
body = "\u0421\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c."
encoded = body.encode("utf-8")
decoded = str(encoded,'utf-8')
print(decoded)
```

Output:

```
Сдать.
```

Comment: still get the same output as before after trying this

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Check the `<meta>` tag at the top of the web-page's HTML code. Does it have a `Content-Type` attribute? Or simply add the link of the website to your post so others can check.

Comment: only found this HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 11:47:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: The problem is that there is no meta tag so I checked the response headers

Comment: If your `Content-Type` is `application/json` you should access your data with `.json` property, not `.text`.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably responding with wrong encoding. You can check it with `r.encoding`. `requests` is using it when you access `.text` property of the response.

You can manually change the encoding to `utf-8` with `r.encoding = "utf-8"` and then access the `.text` property.

```
r.encoding = "utf-8"

# Now r.text shoud be fine
body_clean = re.search('"body_clean": "', r.text)
body_clean1 = re.search('", "attachments', r.text)
body = r.text[body_clean.end():body_clean1.start()]
print (body)
```

`requests` [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)